# Rails 4 - will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

This is my first attempt using will_paginate (I know! Where have I been??)

titles_controller.erb

```
  def index
    @titles = Title.active.sorted.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% will_paginate @titles.each do |title| %>
```

Error:

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<Enumerator:0x00000002bacaf0>
```

WTF am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please read will paginate [docs](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki). You need to write:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

There is no need for adding `each`.

So entire view would look like:

```
<% @titles.each do |title| %>
  <!-- do smth with title -->
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @titles %>
```

Comment: Thanks - I did read the docs, but thought the will_paginate call went at top .  Got it now.

Comment: Hey, sorry if this sounded rough, it was not my intention ;)

Answer (score 3):

In your case you dont acctually need to write:

```
<%= will_paginate @titles %>
```

Because it is in the context of the title_controller, will_paginate will assume their is a @titles variable available. Thus it is possible to just write:

```
<%= will_paginate %>
```